# WebView and runnables

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-webview

I am encountering some very obscure issues with a super basic app I have created.

Application rundown:

1. Main Activity - Shows a login screen where the app submits the username and password to an api. Once this is complete, an intent is sent to start the next activity
2. Download Activity - This activity downloads a bunch of files from a server and puts them in the Downloads folder for use later on. Once all downloads are complete, another intent is sent to start the third and final activity. This activity displays a progress bar for the file downloads.
3. Web View Activity - This activity starts and launches a Runnable. This runnable is designed to call a function, then 5 minutes later, re-run itself, ad infinitum. the function it runs creates a WebView in a layout (the layout has a container layout that is used so we can dynamically create the webview every time). A basic HTML page (in the Downloads folder) is loaded into the Web View.

So, I launched the app and it started working no problems. The HTML file was loaded, and I left the office.

I came back to the app this morning, and the Web View was not visible, and the login screen (the view for the first activity, was on the screen.

I quit the app and checked the app I'm using to record the logcat. It showed the Runnable firing every 1-2 minutes, instead of 5 (300,000 milliseconds). Weird.

So I trawled through about 12 hours of logcat, with the runnable launching every couple of minutes (again, it should be 5!). No sign of app failure.

Is there a chance the Web View could be running, but "underneath" the layout for the first activity? If so, what would cause that?

Below is my code for the Web View Activity:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

Timer autoUpdate;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Handler webHandler = new Handler();

Intent intent;
ArrayList<String> advertArray;
ProgressDialog pd;
File playlistFile;
File path;
File adFile;

private int currentIndex = 0;

private LinearLayout webContainer;
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i("MYAPP", "Starting WebViewActivity");

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    webContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.webviewContainer);

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("runnable", "loadHTML");
        loadHtml();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 600000);
    }
};

private void loadHtml() {
    intent = getIntent();
    advertArray = (ArrayList<String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("adverts");

    Log.i("advert array size", ""+advertArray.size());

    Log.d("main", "ACTIVITY ONCREATE");

    webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    webContainer.removeAllViews();

    webContainer.addView(webView);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

    path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/files");

    String index = advertArray.get(currentIndex);
    Log.i("advert array index", index);
    adFile = new File(path + "/" + index + "/index.html");

    webView.loadUrl("file:///" + adFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

}
```

Comment: `So, I launched the app and it started working no problems. The HTML file was loaded, and I left the office`. Did you by any chance rotate the device(portrait to landscape or vice versa) after starting the activity? This could explain `Runnable firing every 1-2 minutes, instead of 5 (300,000 milliseconds)`. And by the way, I noticed that the delay is actually 10 minutes: `handler.postDelayed(this, 600000);`.

Comment: Ah sorry, i changed the code afterwards, it was 5 seconds, I changed it to do more testing :) As for rotating the device, it is a HDMI stick which I am sure lacks the accelerometer, but also, it was left untouched on a desk. It certainly wasn't jiggled every couple of minutes.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. If I run your code on my device > change the orientation ONCE after 2.5 minutes > I will have a Runnable firing every 2.5 minutes (as opposed to 5) for _whatever_ length of time the app remains running. The reasoning: On orientation change, the activity is recreated. When this happens, you will have 2 Runnable threads firing up every 5 minutes.

Comment: I see your point, but this device has no accelerometer, and the manifest file has the screen orientation set to landscape.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening then.